# Flutter: make build-time environment variables available to code

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, compile-time

How can I have build-time environment variables available to code within a Flutter app? (My specific use case is to inject app version number and commit hash into a debug screen. This information is available at build time, but not at runtime).

I had hoped to be able to do something like:

`flutter run --dart-define=APP_VERSION=0.1.2`

And then,

`const appVersion = String.fromEnvironment('APP_VERSION', defaultValue: 'development');`

But this doesn't seem to work (I'm using Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5), and I'm not sure that is a supported feature in Flutter.

Answer (score 15):

Starting from version 1.17 you actually can do that. Recently beta and dev channel got changes that allows you to define compile-time variables. Also you can define multiple variables like this

`flutter run --dart-define=APP_VERSION=0.1.2 --dart-define=SOME_OTHER_VAR=SOME_OTHER_VALYE`

Also it seems that those changes was cherrypicked, so quite possibly that we will see them in upcoming stable release (fingers crossed)

**Update**

So a new stable version of flutter is just rolled out. And it contains these changes with `--dart-define`. So starting from 1.17 you can use this key to define compile-time variables for your Flutter project.

Comment: There's [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870) with this right now if you _don't_ use `const` when retrieving the value on Flutter mobile clients.

Comment: You do not have to do the double equals thing.  This works:  `--dart-define APP_VERSION=0.1.2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flavors` to execute differents `main.dart` and inside these files you can set your values. But if you need to change build number when you build your app, you can use `--build-number` flag.

Comment: Well, it's not workable to have a different `main.dart` for each version number or commit hash you might want to use. I'll investigate `--build-name` / `--build-number` for versioning, but it's not obvious how those could be accessed from code, nor do they help get other values (like a commit hash) available into the source.