# Use same method to get env vironment in flutter from build command than from .env file

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) package to set environment variables in flutter in a .env .

To read the variables I have to have this is my main.dart

```
Future main() async {
  await DotEnv().load('.env');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And then read like this

```
print(DotEnv().env['VAR_NAME']);
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039080/flutter-make-build-time-environment-variables-available-to-code) question, I can also add variables in the build command like this

```
flutter run --dart-define=APP_VERSION=0.1.2
```

And then to read the ones set in the build command, I have to do this

```
const appVersion = String.fromEnvironment('APP_VERSION', defaultValue: 'development');
```

Is there please a way that I can read variables set in either the .env file or the build command the same way?

I will have the variables in my .env file for local development, and the in dev and prod environments they will be set via commands. So how can I find a way that works for both cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the package you mentioned, but a fairly safe bet would be as follows:

Create a singleton class that is responsible for handling environment variables:

```dart
final env = Env._();

class Env {
    Env._();  // private constructor to prevent accidental initialization
}
```

Create a method that gets an environment variable from its string, and choose something to default to. IMO I would give precedence to command line args, but that is a matter of taste:

```dart
String get(String key, {String defaultValue}) {
   final fromFile = DotEnv().env[key];
   final fromArgs = String.fromEnvironment(key);

//    return the value from command line if it exists
//    if not, return the value from .env file
//    if still null, return a default
   return fromArgs ?? fromFile ?? defaultValue;
}
```

You can then access the data globally using:

```dart
env.get('MY_VARIABLE_NAME', defaultValue: 'hello');
```

For even more brevity, you can use Dart's callable classes, by renaming `get()` to `call()`, and then consume it using:

```dart
env('MY_VARIABLE_NAME', defaultValue: 'hello');
```